# Custom validation javascript function always returns the drop down list's selected value as 0

Tags: asp.net

On my page I have a text box that uses a custom validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cv_Question" ControlToValidate="tb_Question" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" OnServerValidate="ValidateQuestion" ClientValidationFunction="CheckQuestion" ForeColor="#FF0000" ValidationGroup="CreateUser"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

The client side validation script that I would like to use always returns 0 for the drop down list SelectedValue, even when the drop down list index has already changed.

I set the drop down list default index to 0 with !Page.IsPostBack

Here is the drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Question" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddl_Question_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Select a question" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="What was the first movie I ever saw?" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>        
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="What is the middle name of my oldest child?" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="In what city was my father born?" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Who was my favourite cartoon character as a child?" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="What is my mother's middle name?" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="In what year did I meet my significant other?" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="What was my first pet's name?" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="First name of the maid of honour at my wedding?" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="First name of my best friend in elementary school?" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Name of my all-time favourite movie character?" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Create a question" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is the client side validation:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function CheckQuestion(sender, args) 
        {        
            var Question =  args.Value.toString();

            <% if(Convert.ToInt32(ddl_Question.SelectedValue) == 11) 
            { %>
                if (Question != "" && Question != null) 
                {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                    return;
                }
            <% } 
            else
            { %>
                alert(<%= Convert.ToInt32(ddl_Question.SelectedValue)%>);
                args.IsValid = true;
                return;
            <% } %>
        }
    </script>
```

I only want to validate the tb_Question if the user has selected "Create a question" from the ddl_Question.

EDIT:

Here is my SelectedIndexChanged method. The tb_Question is made visible when the user selects "Create a question". This happens before any validation occurs.

```
protected void ddl_Question_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(ddl_Question.SelectedValue) == 11)
        {
            Question.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Question.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my recommendation is to use simple JavaScript

So instead of doing that, use JavaScript and maybe jQuery like this

jQuery Nuget: https://nuget.org/packages/jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function CheckQuestion(sender, args) 
    {        
        var Question =  args.Value.toString();
        var questionID = '<%= this.ddl_Question.ClientID %>';
        var currentQuestion = $("#" + questionID).val();

        if (currentQuestion == '11')
        { 
            if (Question != "" && Question != null) 
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                return;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            alert(currentQuestion);
            args.IsValid = true;
            return;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did my ddl_Question_SelectedIndexChanged event not post back to the server? The user must first select "Create a question" in order for the tb_Question to be visible. SelectedIndexChanged has already fired before the client side validation function occurs..

Comment: The problem with using JavaScript as you said is that args corresponds to tb_Question not ddl_Question.

Comment: Ok I already updated the answer, pls let me know if this fixes the problem

Comment: Yep that fixed it. Thanks. I still don't understand why ddl_Question SelectedValue was returning 0, even after the SelectedIndexChanged event fired on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more likely in the Convert.ToInt32 call since this utility method returns zero when the value passed to it is null (you can check MSDN to validate this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) The SelectedValue property is very likely null at this point even though the selected index is zero. Try setting the SelectedValue programmatically and see I that makes any difference.

Comment: I am not sure why it would be null. The user has to select "Create a question" before the tb_Question becomes visible. This is accomplished via the ddl_Question_SelectedIndexChanged event. This event functions properly. The once the tb_Question becomes visible, I modify it and the custom validator fires calling the client side validation which does not work properly.